# App crashes when trying to copy text on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, string, uipasteboard

I program an "encryption app" that encrypts texts in a simple way. This is the code:

```
let smallLetters: String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
let bigLetters: String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

let input: String = encryptTextField.text!
    
    encryptTextField.text! = ""
    
    var value: String = ""
    
    for c in input {
        let otherChars: String = " !§$%&/()=?´`#+'*-_.:,;<>^°@€{}≠¿|][¢¶“¡≤≈ç√∫~µ@€öäüÜÖÄ"
        
        for i in otherChars {
            if c == i {
                value += String(i)
                print("i")
            }
        }
        
        var dCount: Int = 0
        var eCount: Int = 0
        
        var dFound: Bool = false
        var eFound: Bool = false
        
        for d in smallLetters {
            if !dFound {
                if c == d {
                    dFound.toggle()
                    
                    let y: Int = smallCount - dCount
                    var z: Int = 1
                    
                    for i in smallLetters {
                        if y == z {
                            print("[\(c) -> \(i)]")
                            value += String(i)
                        }
                        
                        z += 1
                    }
                } else {
                    dCount += 1
                }
            }
        }
        for e in bigLetters {
            if !eFound {
                
                if c == e {
                    eFound.toggle()
                    
                    let y: Int = bigCount - eCount
                    var z: Int = 1
                    
                    for i in bigLetters {
                        if y == z {
                            print("[\(c) -> \(i)]")
                            
                            value += String(i)
                        }
                        
                        z += 1
                    }
                } else {
                    eCount += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    let maximumChars: Int = 15
    
    var string: String = ""
    var i: Int = 1
    
    var b: Bool = false
    
    for c in value {
        if !b {
            if i <= maximumChars {
                string += String(c)
            } else {
                string += "..."
                b = true
            }
            
            i += 1
        }
    }
    
    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Encoded!", message: "Your input is now encrypted / decrypted.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let cancel: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.encryptTextField.text! = value
        print("OK")
        
        self.encryptTextField.placeholder = "Enter a text to encrypt..."
    })
    let copy: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Copy!", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Copy!")
        
        let pasteboard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.string! = value
        
        self.encryptTextField.placeholder = "'" + string + "' was copied!"
    })
    
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    alert.addAction(copy)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So that I can quickly insert the encrypted text into another app (e.g. WhatsApp) I use this code (simplified):

```
let pasteboard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
pasteboard.string! = "Hello World!"
```

The code works in the simulator: The encrypted text is copied and I can paste it with a double click (see picture).

[Paste encrypted text with a double click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZamT.png)

But when I run the app on my mobile phone (iPhone 8), the app crashes at this point!

Does anyone know a solution or at least know why?

Comment: What is the exception/crash message?

Comment: I dont know. I can't see the error message because I'm running the app on my phone. Are the error messages displayed in Xcode when the phone remains connected to the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to not force unwrap optional variables in your code.

I highly recommend to read more about Optionals in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional).

`let input: String = encryptTextField.text!`

The text in a UITextField can be nil. The data type is a String optional(`String?`)

Instead of the above, use `if let` statements to safely unwrap optionals!

```swift
if let input = encryptTextField.text{
   // Your logic/code to process input as String goes here
}
```

Similarly, You can remove the force unwrapping("!") done here.

1. `encryptTextField.text! = ""`. Just use `encryptTextField.text = ""`

2. `pasteboard.string! = value` You can remove the force unwrapping("!") done here.

3. `pasteboard.string! = "Hello World!"`

Basically only force unwrap variables if you for sure know that the value that the optional variable holds is not nil!

**Force unwrapping optional variables that hold a nil value will crash you app!**

Comment: The app doesn't crash at this point. It only crashes when I press the "Copy" button in the AlertController (below in the code)

Comment: Yes its due to an optional `pasteboard.string! = value` being force unwrapped. 
You can just have it like `pasteboard.string = value`  :)

I have listed all the places where forceunwrapping is done so you can avoid crashes in those places as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your answer correctly. I revised my code and ran the app again on my iPhone. Now it's working! Thank you for your quick reply :)